Slow GET request speed for tiny JS asset in S3 (west coast to east coast)
I have a JS file in a S3 bucket which is intended to not be cached (can't put it to CDN). It is tiny 756B. Yet the GET requests seem to be very slow. Sometimes I can see times over a second long. These request hover around 500ms on average.
I'm looking at requests from US west coast. My bucket doesn't have a region set, but as I understand the region would be us-east-1 in that case. West to East US shouldn't be taking that long, right?
What can I do to improve the download speed of this file ?

Some data on US East coast to West coast latency.

Also, you absolutely can use a CDN, for instance CloudFront allows you to specify a min TTL of 0 seconds.
